# How to get the active tab In Angular Material2

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I want to get which [tab](https://material.angular.io/components/component/tabs) is active. I tried to use a `@ViewChild` decorator and accessing the element properties that way, but it returns `null`.

**Component:**

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'material-app',
  template: `
  <md-tab-group #tabGroup>
      <md-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</md-tab>
      <md-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2</md-tab>
  </md-tab-group>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('tabGroup') tabGroup;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.tabGroup); // MdTabGroup Object
    console.log(this.tabGroup.selectedIndex); // null
  }

}
```

[Plunker Preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/2qjAW8G4FDCkrqVWKeHG?p=preview)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure if I understood well your question because, by default the index always starts counting from zero **unless** you set manually the **[selectedIndex]** `property`.

Anyway, if you really want to see which tab is selected on *initialization* you could implement the `AfterViewInit` interface and do the following:

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {

...

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('afterViewInit => ', this.tabGroup.selectedIndex);
  }
}
```

On other hand, if you want to check which tab is selected based on **changes** (what makes more sense), here you go:

**HTML:**

```
<mat-tab-group #tabGroup (selectedTabChange)="tabChanged($event)">
  <mat-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

**Component:**

```
tabChanged(tabChangeEvent: MatTabChangeEvent): void {
  console.log('tabChangeEvent => ', tabChangeEvent);
  console.log('index => ', tabChangeEvent.index);
}
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-c5zsp2)</kbd>

Comment: The second case is what I was looking for, but the first one is useful to know too. Thank you @developer033!

Comment: Hi! I used this code and I've got a error that "this.tabGroup" is undefined. Only after onSelectChange Angular "see" this dom element. It's like ngAfterViewInit() doesn't work for me. Do you know what's going on?

Comment: For the first option, how would you get the _name_ (instead of the index) of the tab that is automatically selected on initialization?

Comment: @FiringBlanks you mean the *label*? If so, you can just access `tabChangeEvent.textLabel`.

Comment: Yes, the label, but I want to get it when the tab-group is first initialized, not listen for when the tabs are changed by the user. I need to know the label of the tab that the tab-group starts with.

Comment: @Budi I've changed the link.

Answer (score 22):

According to Material documentation Angular Material tabs output an event on tab change `@Output() selectedTabChange: EventEmitter<MatTabChangeEvent>`

**Your Template:**

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="tabChanged($event)">
  <mat-tab>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>Tab 1</ng-template>
    Tab Content
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>Tab 2</ng-template>
    Tab Content
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

**Your Typescript:**

```
import { MatTabChangeEvent } from '@angular/material';

public tabChanged(tabChangeEvent: MatTabChangeEvent): void {
    console.log(tabChangeEvent);
}
```

Comment: how can you know the tab index when the page loads?. Currently when the page load, your method does not log the index. Any help with this is highly appreciated as I have been stuck for a while. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Thats right selectedTabChange  only emits tabChangeEvent only on click when tub is changed. Not sure if there is a way that will work out of the box. You could try  <mat-tab-group #tabGroup> @ViewChild('tabGroup') tabGroup; ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.tabGroup.selectedIndex);
  }

Answer (score 12):

"@angular/material": "^**6.2.1**". The way to get selected tab index **on-load** (after template has loaded) and when the **tab is focused**.

**my.component.ts**

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('tabGroup') tabGroup;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
      console.log(this.tabGroup.selectedIndex);
    }

    public tabChanged(tabChangeEvent: MatTabChangeEvent): void {
      console.log(tabChangeEvent);
    }
}
```

**my.component.html**

```
<mat-tab-group #tabGroup (focusChange)="tabChanged($event)" [selectedIndex]="1">
    <mat-tab>
        <ng-template mat-tab-label>Tab 1</ng-template>
        Tab Content
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab>
        <ng-template mat-tab-label>Tab 2</ng-template>
        Tab Content
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can get active `index` of active [`angular material`](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) tabs

`.html` file

```
<div>    
<mat-tab-group #tabRef (selectedTabChange)="logChange(tabRef.selectedIndex)">
  <mat-tab label="ALL"></mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Delivered"></mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Pending"></mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Cancelled"></mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>    
</div>
```

`.ts` file

```
logChange(index)
{
  console.log(index);
}
```

Don't forget to add import in `app.module.ts` file

`import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';`

Answer (score 0):

By default tab with index 0 is shown by mat-tab-group. later on as and when the other tab is selected, the index also changes. This can be detected by **MatTabChangeEvent**

**HTML Content**

```
    <mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="onTabChange($event)">
    
        <mat-tab label="First Tab">
         <p>Hello, Tab 0</p>
        </mat-tab>
    
        <mat-tab label="Second Tab">
         <p>Hello, Tab 1</p>
        </mat-tab>
    
        <mat-tab label="Third Tab">
         <p>Hello, Tab 2</p>
        </mat-tab>
    
    </mat-tab-group>
```

**.ts file content**

```
onTabChange(event : MatTabChangeEvent) {
    
    console.log(event.index);
    // do something based on selected tab index
}
```