# How to make a specific tab to be active on Angular Material Tab Component

Tags: angular, tabs, angular-material2

I am working on the Angular Material's Tabs Component (https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview)

By default, the first tab is selected after the page load.

How can I change to some another specific tab to already be selected when the page loads.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the active tab In Angular Material2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41653180/how-to-get-the-active-tab-in-angular-material2)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `[selectedIndex]="selectedIndex"` for your tab to specifically pick which tab to be display

Comment: in addition, once the tabs have been rendered, if you want to change it programmatically use  `[(selectedIndex)]="selectedIndex"` .