# PrimeNg TabView with ConfirmDialog

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng, tabview

I'm trying to use PrimeNg TabView component along with confirmDialog unsuccessfully, here is my code:

```
<p-tabView (onChange)="onTabChange($event)" [(activeIndex)]="index">...</p-tabView> 


  onTabChange(event){
    this.confirmationService.confirm({
      message: 'Do you confirm ?',
      accept:  () => {
      this.index = event.index;
      },
      reject:() =>{        }
      });
   }
```

Do you have an idea on how to prevent or allow tab change using confirm dialog ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on similar [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41653180/how-to-get-the-active-tab-in-angular-material2) for material design tabs, here is the solution for my issue:

1. in **html** Declare a local variable referencing TabView DOM object:

   `<p-tabView #onglets>...</p-tabView>`
2. in ***component.ts***, change default function called when click on tab with specific
   function to match your case:

   `@ViewChild('onglets') onglets: TabView;
    this.onglets.open = this.interceptOngletChange.bind(this);
    ...
    interceptOngletChange(event: Event, tab: TabPanel){
      const result = confirm(`Do you really want to leave the tab?`);
      return result && TabView.prototype.open.apply(this.onglets, argumentsList);
       });
     }`

Comment: what is argument list here?

Comment: whatever arguments you need to pass

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. Needed show dialog before tab change.
My solution:

HTML

```html
<p-tabView #tabView (onChange)="onChange($event)" />
```

TS

```js
@ViewChild('tabView') tabView: TabView;

  onChange(event: any) {

    const previoustab = this.tabView.tabs[this.prevIndex]; //saved previous/initial index
    previoustab.selected = true;
    const selectedTab = this.tabView.tabs[event.index];
    selectedTab.selected = false;
    this.tabView.activeIndex = this.prevIndex;
    this.nextIndex= event.index;
  }

  GoToNextTab() {

    this.tabView.activeIndex = this.nextIndex;
    this.prevIndex= this.nextIndex;
    this.tabView.open(undefined, this.tabView.tabs[this.nextIndex]);
  }
```

With this code you will stay on the selected tab without tab style changes.